# Can I boot back into Windows 10 after installing Windows 11 on a separate drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, uefi, windows-11, asus

I needed to download Windows 11 for one of my projects so I got the ISO for the beta channel (build 22000.194), made a bootable USB with it and installed Windows 11 on a freshly formatted SSD that I had.

The problem is that somehow booting into Windows 11 broke my ability to boot into Windows 10 off of my primary SSD in my computer. All of the files for Windows 10 are still there as far as I can tell, but my primary SSD no longer shows up in my Asus UEFI as a bootable drive, and Windows 10 doesn't show up as an option for dual boot in Windows 11, even though I can literally see where all the system files are.

I have tried unplugging my new drive with Windows 11 on it, but I just get an error screen on startup saying that my computer needs to be repaired. Did I break my Windows 10 install permanently, or is there a way that I can boot back into Windows 10?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Windows 11 might have invalidated the boot EFI partition
on the old disk.

This will return the boot code:

- Create a
  [boot media for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)
- Unplug the Windows 11 drive
- Boot from the boot media
- [Run Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Note: I don't believe you will have a license problem with Windows 10.

Comment: I think you must roll back Windows 11 in order to put the Windows 10 license back in force. it is one license for one operating system.

Comment: @John: The Windows 10 license is locked to the hardware fingerprint. It couldn't have been invalidated by installing Windows 11, or it would have been impossible to rollback to 10.

Comment: I understand how that works. but both at once on two disks has likely generated an issue. Windows insider is not meant to be used this way.  At least I have not seen both systems simultaneously on two disks.  Let's see if the OP is helped.

Answer (score 0):

> I got the ISO for the beta channel (build 22000.194), made a bootable
> usb with it and installed windows 11 on a freshly formatted SSD that I
> had

This is the Insider version of Windows 11 and that would have used your Windows 10 license to install Windows 11 Insider.

Go to Windows Settings, Update, Windows Insider and see if you can still roll back to Windows 10. I am not certain because of the way you installed Windows 11.

Be prepared to reinstall Windows 10.

Possible way forward:  Do a proper installation of Windows 11 for future and then get a Windows 10 license and install that as a Virtual Machine. Most anything you can do in Windows 10 can also be done in Windows 11.

Comment: Ok it makes sense that windows would not let me have 2 machines off of the same license, but I still don't understand how I am unable to boot from an operating system that still has all of it's files on my ssd. I'm wondering how could installing windows 11 break my install of windows 10 when they aren't on the same drive?

Comment: I have not done precisely what you have done, but I have installed Insider and that uses the Windows 10 license and activation which in turn I think explains why you cannot re-use Windows 10 at the same time (by rebooting).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I upgraded to Windows 11 but I had some important windows encrypted files on my machine.

However, I managed to solve it.

So the root issue is that the BCD file in the UEFI partition only points to the Windows 11 install.

To fix this I followed this video: https://youtu.be/CZ17JrgFFhw?si=UXydwSD81yH5kNOe

I noticed in Windows 11 that my drive letters changed, but in the windows 10 recovery console they were the old letters.

Ended up regenerating the EFI folder (following the video above) pointing to my old `C:` drive.

Currently haven't changed the BSD back to Windows 11 or looked into dual booting yet, but likely the steps will be similar but using the windows 11 installer instead